# Change 70° F to 70 in Excel for Office 365

Tags: excel-formula

I have "70° F" formatted as text in a cell. I want to strip  the "° F" and just have "70" formatted as number in an adjacent cell

Answer (score 0):

Use SUBSTITUTE:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"° F","")
```

[image]

Comment: @Mike please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.